# Installing Haskell math-functions-0.3.1.0 hangs

Tags: haskell, cabal

Trying to install Haskell datasets (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/datasets).
The installation hangs when building math-functions-0.3.1.0.
Tried to install individual dependencies, and again had the same result at building  math-functions-0.3.1.0.
I use Haskell Platform for Windows 8.6.3.

[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQgyK.png)

Answer (score -1):

Used cabal install instead of cabal new-install and the issue was resolved.